# display driver and number of shifts involved in that are over 1

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select dr_drvname, count(sh_drvnum)
from driver join shift on dr_drvnum = sh_drvnum
where count(sh_drvnum) not like '1'
group by dr_drvname;
```

this code doesn't work. I know there needs to be a subquery involved somewhere but I am unable to figure out what and where. Thanks.

Comment: look up the keyword `Having`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it solved here's the answer

```
select dr_drvname, count(sh_drvnum)
from driver join shift on dr_drvnum = sh_drvnum
group by dr_drvname
having count(sh_drvnum) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, pre-aggregating the count prior to the join:

```
select dr_drvname,
       shift_count
from   driver inner join (
         select   sh_drvnum,
                  count(*) shift_count
         from     shift
         group by sh_drvnum
         having   count(*) > 1) on (dr_drvname = sh_drvname)
```